# Correct JSON format for GCM message

Tags: c#, .net, json, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

heres my JSON

```
   var postData = 
                     "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + pushNotificationState.RegistrationId + "\" ], "+
                         "\"data\": {\""+ pushNotificationState.NotificationData.NotificationData + "\"}";
```

registration Id and notification data are variables. I'm getting a 400 response from the GCM sever saying JSON is incorrect format. Can anyone pick where I have gone wrong?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have one open `{` but have two close `}`.

```
var postData = "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + pushNotificationState.RegistrationId + "\" ], " + "\"data\": \""+ pushNotificationState.NotificationData.NotificationData + "\"}";
```

Comment: cheers for the reply and help but the server is still staying bad json format.

Comment: I think you should add a breakpoint to see exactly value of postData, and confirm the format. Easy way to check if it is a JSON well-formatted string is viewing it by some JSON viewers, like http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/

Comment: You can send the debug value to my inbox so I can check the format for you

Comment: I'm getting registration_ids is not an array.. Which is strange because in the example format it doesn't look like an array to me..

Comment: it was after a simple String array. My bad.

Answer (score 1):

Use some [Json](http://json.codeplex.com/) tools, instead of creating your string by hand. Otherwise you'd have problems if some of string variables contain `{`,`}`,`"` etc.

```
var json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(
            new {
                registration_ids = new[] { pushNotificationState.RegistrationId },
                data = pushNotificationState.NotificationData.NotificationData
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   var postData =      "{ \"registration_ids\": [ \"" + pushNotificationState.RegistrationId + "\" ]}, "+
                             "\"data\": {\""+ pushNotificationState.NotificationData.NotificationData + "\"}";
```

Try replacing it with that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code to create the request object, then convert to json.

```
public  class GCMRequest
{
    public GCMRequest()
    {
        data = new PayLoad();
    }
    public List<string> registration_ids;
    public PayLoad data;
}
public class PayLoad
{
    public string key;
}
```

you can create the request as below

```
GCMRequest req = new GCMRequest();
List<string> tokens = new List<string>();
// .. fill the tokens to the 'tokens' list
req.registration_ids = tokens;
req.data.key = "Hi, how are you"; // message you want to send
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(req);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: What is the purpose of the PayLoad class?